# Valgrind showing odd "if" statement cycle consumption

Tags: arm, profiling, valgrind, callgrind

I'm running valgrind / callgrind on a program and when I view the source code tab in kachegrind to find out where cycles are being spent in a particular file, it shows a huge percentage (63%) of time on a line that doesn't make sense to me - all it has is an "if" statement. I figured it was really referring to the computationally expensive lines above the "if" statement.

The types of the variables in the screenshot below are a combination of float and int - I've tried converting all the variables to float, but I get the same high % number but the line number changes to a few lines above (with equally benign looking code, i.e. an assignment or a conditional)

Could there be some problem with the line number that's being reported?

[image: kcachegrind screenshot]

Comment: Yes, there can be problem with line number reporting when the code was compiled with optimization. Try to recompile this code file with debugging information enabled and with less optimizations (`-g -O0`, `-g -O1`); check also disassembly tab. You have not only float vars, but also integer consts. What is ABI of your ARM, is there hardware floating point unit, is it used by your compiler (check `-mfloat-abi=` or equalent of your compiler, there are several variants in gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html)